# How to attach missing java JDK sources in Netbeans 7

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

When I try to navigate in NetBeans to some JDK source code it only shows that it's compiled code and the source code is missing and I can attach it. After attaching the source with the "Attach.." button nothing happens? Where should I attach the source code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tools->JavaPlatforms->JSE{choose your jdk}->source tab->Add jar/folder {chose src.zip from installed JDK path.}