# Where can I download the JavaFX 2.2 source code?

Tags: javafx-2, netbeans-7

I need to link in `Netbeans 7.2.1` to the `source of JavaFX 2.2.3`, I've looked on the Oracle web site ... but I didn't find it ! any help is a welcome plz

Comment: Why this question is closed? This is a specific problem, and it does not imply any 'opinionated' answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

JavaFX 2.2 is only partially open source.
You can download the parts which are open from the zip link at:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt

**JavaFX 8**

JavaFX 8 is completely open source today.

Source for building JavaFX 8 (and the [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) design tool) is available at:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt

Source code for later versions (including Java 8 updates), is in the source code forest, an overview of which is at:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx

- [Instructions for building JavaFX 8 with OpenJDK 8](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX)

If you don't need to build JavaFX 8 and just want the runtime sources in a zip, those are in the `javafx-src.zip` file from the [JDK 8 download](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

On OS X, the `javafx-src.zip` file is located at:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/javafx-src.zip

**IDE Setup**

Instructions for configuring Idea to understand the source are here:

[JavaFX source code not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407017/javafx-source-code-not-showing-in-intellij-idea)

For NetBeans, you could try:

[How to attach missing java JDK sources in Netbeans 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071265/how-to-attach-missing-java-jdk-sources-in-netbeans-7)

Comment: thank u for the answer, So it is **partially open-source**.

Comment: @jewelsea the first link's folder has not been modified in 10 months, so apparently it is outdated

Comment: @jiujitsu the JavaFX 2.2 source link is not currently outdated. The latest tag on that branch is 2.2-b21, which is the latest released non-preview version of JavaFX today.

Comment: @Jewelsea And how do openjfx major.minor version match with the one supplied with oracle? 2.2.3 == ?

Comment: @maocha_ak see: [How to get the version number of JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266997/how-to-get-the-version-number-of-javafx)

Comment: Just for the case someone else was looking, too: If you have the JDK installed, you don't have to download the source jar separately. I found the source jar at the following location `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\javafx-src.zip` on my machine running Windows 8.

Comment: `javafx-src.zip` is NOT in Java 1.7. And I'm still looking for a DOWNLOAD because all I see in those links are REPOSITORIES which I can't check out because the development PC at work doesn't have internet and the internet PC only has a browser!

Comment: @Mark there are zip/bz2/gz download links in the repository viewer for portions of JavaFX included with Java 1.7 that were open sourced.  Here is a [direct link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/archive/tip.zip).  Public updates for Java 7 ended in April 2015, so the Java 7 platform is largely obsolete.  For most people, the JavaFX 2.2 source download link is not applicable, as they will be using Java 8+, where the source is included with the JDK distribution.

Answer (score -5):

believe me if you already have installed latest version of jdk and set jdk version in netbeans then it will not ask.

in my case i found jar files in folder C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib
just add all jar file in your project and you have done.

Comment: This answer will work for JavaFX binary code, but the original question is asking about the JavaFX source code.

Comment: Exactly for the same reason as above