# JavaFX Observable Value

Tags: javafx

I am beginning to cover GUIs using JavaFX on my own and I was just curious as to how instances of ObservableValue can "monitor" a particular value for changes. It is an important concept for property binding but my book doesn't really explain how they accomplish this and I'm just curious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic behind the Observable types. Actually, it's really simple:

The only way to change the value of a *Property class from the outside is by it's setter method, which just triggers the listener.

Answer (score 3):

It is an [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) you can read up on the [observer design](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html).  If you want to find the specifics of how it is implemented in JavaFX, then study the [JavaFX source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553375/where-can-i-download-the-javafx-2-2-source-code/13553814#13553814), in particular the [property source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/base/src/main/java/javafx/beans), a key class involved is the [ExpressionHelper](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/binding/ExpressionHelper.java).