# Looks up JavaFX node style settings

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to extract the entire css settings for a given node? I am looking to print out the list of CSS styles applied to a node for debugging purposes so that I can iteratively tweak certain settings.

Comment: You could review [JDK-8091202 CSS Style Object Model in Java](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091202), it was never completed, but there might be some info on some private API detailed there that you might be able to find in the [JavaFX source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553375/where-can-i-download-the-javafx-2-2-source-code/13553814#13553814) and use to retrieve the info you are looking for.