# Difference in lambda performances?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, lambda, java-8

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294846/performance-difference-between-java-8-lambdas-and-anonymous-inner-classes) is not a duplicate of my question. I checked it and it is more about inner anonymous classes.

I was curious about Lambda expressions and tested the following :

- Given an array of ten thousand entries, what would be the faster to delete certain indexes : Lamba expression or For-Loop with an if test inside?

First results were not surprising in the fact that I did not know what I was going to come up with :

```
final int NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES = 10_000;
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] myWords = "Testing Lamba expressions with this String array".split(" ");
    
for (int i = 0 ; i < NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES ; i++){
    myList.add(myWords[i%6]);
}
        
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
// BOTH TESTS WERE RUN SEPARATELY OF COURSE
// PUT THE UNUSED ONE IN COMMENTS WHEN THE OTHER WAS WORKING
        
// 250 milliseconds for the Lambda Expression
myList.removeIf(x -> x.contains("s"));
        
// 16 milliseconds for the traditional Loop
for (int i = NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
    if (myList.get(i).contains("s")) myList.remove(i);
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + " milliseconds");
```

But then, I decided to change the constant `NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES` to one million and here is the result :

```
final int NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES = 1_000_000;
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] myWords = "Testing Lamba expressions with this String array".split(" ");
    
for (int i = 0 ; i < NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES ; i++){
    myList.add(myWords[i%6]);
}
    
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
// BOTH TESTS WERE RUN SEPARATELY OF COURSE
// PUT THE UNUSED ONE IN COMMENTS WHEN THE OTHER WAS WORKING
    
// 390 milliseconds for the Lambda Expression
myList.removeIf(x -> x.contains("s"));
    
// 32854 milliseconds for the traditional Loop
for (int i = NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){ 
    if (myList.get(i).contains("s")) myList.remove(i);
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + " milliseconds");
```

To make things simpler to read, here are the results :

```
|        |  10.000 | 1.000.000 |
| LAMBDA |  250ms  |   390ms   | 156% evolution
|FORLOOP |   16ms  |  32854ms  | 205000+% evolution
```

I have the following questions :

- What is magic behind this? How do we come to such a big difference for the array and not for the lambda when the indexes to work with is *100.
- In terms of performance, how do we know when to use Lambdas and when to stick to traditional ways to work with data?
- Is this a specific behavior of the `List` method? Are other Lambda expression also produce random performances like this one?

Comment: You are possibly being mislead by micro-benchmarking anomalies.  Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: you can check the source code of ArrayList.removeIf(filter)

Comment: if you haven't, set up your IDE to show JDK sources so you can do your own research. [Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/426131/1362755), [Netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11071313/1362755)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote a JMH benchmark to measure this. There are 4 methods in it:

- `removeIf` on an `ArrayList`.
- `removeIf` on a `LinkedList`.
- iterator with `iterator.remove()` on an `ArrayList`.
- iterator with `iterator.remove()` on a `LinkedList`.

The point of the benchmark is to show that `removeIf` and an iterator should provide the same performance, but that it is not the case for an `ArrayList`.

By default, `removeIf` uses an iterator internally to remove the elements so we should expect the same performance with `removeIf` and with an `iterator`.

---

Now consider an `ArrayList` which uses an array internally to hold the elements. Everytime we call `remove`, the remaining elements after the index have to be shifted by one; so each time a lot of elements have to be copied. When an iterator is used to traverse the `ArrayList` and we need to remove an element, this copying needs to happen again and again, making this very slow. For a `LinkedList`, this is not the case: when an element is deleted, the only change is the pointer to the next element.

So why is `removeIf` as fast on an `ArrayList` as on a `LinkedList`? Because it is actually overriden and it does not use an iterator: the code actually marks the elements to be deleted in a first pass and then deletes them (shifting the remaining elements) in a second pass. An optimization is possible in this case: instead of shifting the remaining elements each time one needs to be removed, we only do it once when we know all the elements that need to be removed.

---

Conclusion:

- `removeIf` should be used when one needs to remove every elements matching a predicate.
- `remove` should be used to remove a single known element.

---

Result of benchmark:

```
Benchmark                            Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
RemoveTest.removeIfArrayList         avgt   30      4,478 ±   0,194  ms/op
RemoveTest.removeIfLinkedList        avgt   30      3,634 ±   0,184  ms/op
RemoveTest.removeIteratorArrayList   avgt   30  27197,046 ± 536,584  ms/op
RemoveTest.removeIteratorLinkedList  avgt   30      3,601 ±   0,195  ms/op
```

Benchmark:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(3)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class RemoveTest {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES = 1_000_000;
    private static final String[] words = "Testing Lamba expressions with this String array".split(" ");

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private LinkedList<String> linkedList;

    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void setUp() {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < NUMBER_OF_LIST_INDEXES ; i++){
            arrayList.add(words[i%6]);
            linkedList.add(words[i%6]);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void removeIfArrayList() {
        arrayList.removeIf(x -> x.contains("s"));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void removeIfLinkedList() {
        linkedList.removeIf(x -> x.contains("s"));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void removeIteratorArrayList() {
        for (ListIterator<String> it = arrayList.listIterator(arrayList.size()); it.hasPrevious();){
            if (it.previous().contains("s")) it.remove();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void removeIteratorLinkedList() {
        for (ListIterator<String> it = linkedList.listIterator(linkedList.size()); it.hasPrevious();){
            if (it.previous().contains("s")) it.remove();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Main.main(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14):

Because `remove(index)` is very expensive :) It needs to copy and shift the rest of elements, and this is done multiple times in your case.

While `removeIf(filter)` does not need to do that. It can sweep once and mark all elements to be deleted; then the final phase copies survivors to the head of list just once.

Comment: I also was surprised when I saw this the first time. Indeed, it basically boils down to the [special implementation of `removeIf` in `ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/94e1a4b10811/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l1364)

Answer (score 1):

I think the performance difference you're seeing is probably due more to `removeIf`'s use of an iterator internally vs. get and remove in your for loop. The answers in this [PAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator) have some good information on the benefits of iterators.

bayou.io's answer is spot on, you can see the [code for removeIf here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.removeIf%28java.util.function.Predicate%29) it does two passes to avoid shifting the remaining elements over and over.