# What am i doing wrong with java 8 lambda Predicate<Integer>?

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-8, predicate

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182102/difference-in-lambda-performances)** is not a duplicate of my question. I checked it and mine is how to use *proper Predicate*, and **THAT** is about differences between removeIf & remove.

I'm beginner Java programmer.
Yesterday, I tried to follow this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-need-lambda-expressions

After I leared how to use Lambda expressions and Predicate, I made my own code to practice.
like, sum all numbers if(n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0).
here is my code.

```
public class Euler1Lambda {
    long max;
    public Euler1Lambda(long max) {
        this.max = max;
    }
public static boolean div3remainder0(int number) {
    return number % 3 == 0;
}

public static boolean div5remainder0(int number) {
    return number % 5 == 0;
}

public long sumAll() {
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<max; i++) {
        if (div3remainder0(i) ||div5remainder0(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

public long sumAllLambda(Predicate<Integer> p) {
    long total = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i< max; i++){
        if (p.test(i)) {
            total += i;
        }
    }
return total;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //conv
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        new Euler1Lambda(100000000).sumAll();
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long conv = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + conv);
    //lambda
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        new Euler1Lambda(100000000).sumAllLambda(n -> div3remainder0(n) || div5remainder0(n));
    }
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lambda = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + lambda);
    System.out.println("lambda / conv : " + (float)lambda/conv);
}
}
```

In this code, did timing tests.
and result is like this.

```
Total execution time conv: 1761
Total execution time lambda: 3266

lambda / conv : 1.8546281
```

As you can see, lambda expression with predicate is slower than simple for-loop.

I have no idea why does the result like this.
What am I doing wrong? or just predicate is too slow way to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let's look at the scale of things. You're talking about a difference of about 1505 ms for 100000000 items, or about 15 *nanoseconds* per item. That overhead is not very substantial.

That said, the overhead is from autoboxing all those `int`s into `Integers` for the sake of the `Predicate<Integer>`. `Predicate::test` takes an `Integer`, so `p.test(i)` is really getting compiled down to `p.test(Integer.valueOf(i))`. That method isn't super duper expensive, but it's not free. Apparently it takes about 15 nanoseconds on your computer.

If you use an [`IntPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/function/Predicate.html) instead — which uses an `int` primitive as its input, and thus avoids the boxing — you'll find that the difference between the direct and lambda-based approach is virtually gone.

Aside from that, there are the usual warnings about microbenchmarking in Java (warmup loops, using a framework like JMH, etc). There is a wealth of knowledge out there about that subject, and I strongly encourage you to read up on it if you want to continue benchmarking quick actions like this.

Comment: thx a lot. :) This answer is really helpful. and I will try to find out more about microbenchmarking in Java.

Comment: I guess, with sufficient warmup, the difference will vanish in either case as the execution time will converge to zero (hint: in all cases the entire operation is side effect free and its result not used anywhere)…

Answer (score 3):

Performance and lambda can be tricky. In your case the use of wrapper type Integer and auto boxing slow down stuff.

Switch

```
public long sumAllLambda(Predicate<Integer> p)
```

to

```
public long sumAllLambda(IntPredicate p)
```

the results are almost the same

```
Total execution time conv: 3190
Total execution time lambda: 3037
lambda / conv : 0.95203763
```

Comment: this simple code also helped me to sovle a problem. thx a lot :)